# CUDA kernel printf of (int) -1 gives wrong output with %d specifier

Tags: cuda, printf, format-specifiers

When telling my computer in C

```
printf("%d",(int)-1);
```

I do expect, and usually get, too, a '-1' response. However, on my Tesla  M2090 Nvidia Card spoken to from my Ubuntu-based Cuda 5.0 this innocent demo program

```
/** cheese.cu */
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> struct SpacePtr
  { size_t size; T* ptr; };

 __global__ void f(SpacePtr<int>* sp)
{
  printf("This _is_ a 'minus one' or ain't it: %d\n",(int)-1);
  // Note: All appears to work fine with %lu instead of %zd
  // Still: How does the size value affect the -1?
  printf("On DEV: Size: %zd, Minus One: %d\n",sp->size,(int)-1);
}

int main()
{
  SpacePtr<int> data; data.ptr = 0; data.size = 168;
  SpacePtr<int>* devPtr = 0;
  cudaMalloc(&devPtr,1);
  cudaMemcpy(devPtr,&data,sizeof(SpacePtr<int>),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  f<<<1,1,0,0>>>(devPtr);
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  cout << "The last error code was " << err << " (" <<
    cudaGetErrorString(err) << ")" << endl;
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

compiled and called via

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 cheese.cu && ./a.out
```

yields the output:

```
The last error code was 0 (no error)
This _is_ a 'minus one' or ain't it: -1
On DEV: Size: 168, Minus One: 10005640
```

The last number actually being some kind of random number (two subseqent calls return different results) as if something was amiss in memory allocation. The (int) before the -1 is already trial and error. The original program did not have it.

And here is the question: Does anybody see, why the -1 is not written, and if so, could you please tell me why? Thanks a lot, Markus.

Comment: Only possible undefined behavior because of `sp->size` may be memory allocation. If not. don't forget recompile code then execute. I guess :) defiantly no problem with `printf("%d",(int)-1);`

Comment: Here is an update to my own question: It appears to work if I use "%lu" for the size_t and "%d" for the infamous "-1". So probably it has to do with that the device for some reason expects C90 style %lu. Still: Outside the kernel code %zd and %d work fine. I keep the question open for I still do not see how a wrong formatter for the size value would destroy the formatting of the -1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check [appendix B.32.1 "Format Specifiers"](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#format-specifiers) of the CUDA C Programming Guide, you will find that the `z` modifier in `%zd` is not supported. You will have to cast to `unsigned long` and use `%lu` as format specifier:

```
printf("On DEV: Size: %lu, Minus One: %d\n",(unsigned long)(sp->size), (int)-1);
```

Comment: I guess that's what one gets for printing the doc thus having an obsolete paper variation around... Your answer restores my faith in not having found a bug in CUDA conserving my faith in the whole thing! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem seems to be that the `%zd` format specifier isn't being honoured by the device printf (I am not sure, off the top of my head whether it is supported).

EDIT:

The documentation for printf in CUDA 5 says this:

> As for standard printf(), format specifiers take the form:
>   %[flags][width][.precision][size]type
>
> The following fields are supported (see widely-available documentation
>   for a complete description of all behaviors):
>
> ```
> Flags: ‘#’ ‘ ‘ ‘0’ ‘+’ ‘-‘
> Width: ‘*’ ‘0-9’
> Precision: ‘0-9’
> Size: ‘h’ ‘l’ ‘ll’
> Type: ‘%cdiouxXpeEfgGaAs’
> ```
>
> Note that CUDA’s printf()will accept any combination of flag, width,
>   precision, size and type, whether or not overall they form a valid
>   format specifier. In other words, “%hd” will be accepted and printf
>   will expect a double-precision variable in the corresponding location
>   in the argument list.

So the `%zd` format specifier for `size_t` isn't supported. Modifying your kernel like this:

```
__global__ void f(SpacePtr<int>* sp)
{
    const int minus_one = -1;
    printf("This _is_ a 'minus one' or ain't it: %d\n", minus_one);
    printf("On DEV: Size: %d, Minus One: %d\n",int(sp->size), minus_one);
}
```

works fine.

Also note you have a pretty major mistake in your host code, although that won't have any effect on the manifest behaviour in your example. You are only allocating and copying one byte for `dev_ptr` which is obviously incorrect. It should look something like:

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtr, sizeof(data));
cudaMemcpy(devPtr, &data, sizeof(data), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

to transfer the full contents of data from host to device.

Comment: At answer: Thanks to you, too. Obviously I should update my doc. I use the Cuda 4.0 Manual. At memory allocation: Eeek. Yes. In my main program I hacked this demo from it is correct though! ;-)